# Is the loss value based on batch data or the whole data?

Tags: function, tensorflow, loss

Thanks for your attention to this quesion. 
And I have a questin to consult you.

When we use tensorflow to calculate a loss funtion,

1. is the loss value based on batch size data or the whole data set?
2. is there anyway to assign trainable weights to different data ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition, it's a batch loss.